# How do you move text from a div into an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move text from inside a `div` into the `value` from an input field but I'm getting `[object Object]` as the output. Can anyone explain why?

```
    input = $('#input').contents();
    $('#output').val(input);
```

Comment: `input` is an object, `val()` expects a String, so it's using `toString()` to convert `input` to a String, giving the results you're seeing.  You want `text()` or `html()` or one of the other text contents retrieval functions, not `contents()`

Comment: Assuming you want to literally move the nodes contained by `input` you could replace `$('#output').val(input)` with `$('#output').append(input)` or `input.appendTo('#output')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spencer.

The [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method won't give you the text, but an object with a collection of the elements it contains. You sould use:

[val method:](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

[text method:](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method.

The line you're looking for is:

```
  $('#input').val($('#div').text());
```

and can be decomposed like this:

```
var textToMove = $('#div').text();
$('#input').val(textToMove);
```

**Here is a full example:**

```js
function move(){
  $('#input').val($('#div').text()); //copy text
  $('#div').text(''); //erase text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input' type='text' value=''>
<div id="div">Hello, Spencer</div>
<button onclick='move()'>Click to move text</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

First get the text content with

```
$("#d").text()
```

Add this to input like

```
$("#y").val($("#d").text());
```

Now you can remove text of div like

```
 $("#d").text("")
```

```js
$("#y").val($("#d").text());
$("#d").text("")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d">text</div>
<input type="text" id="y"/>
```

**Note:**

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.contents()` method allows to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. and the results includes text nodes and comment nodes as well as HTML elements in the resulting jQuery object.  [Here](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

That's why you are getting `object`. you really need to use `.text()` here to get the text contents only.

Comment: This code does not actually answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @Tibrogargan how does it not ?  He is trying to move the text and this really does the same No ?

Comment: His question is "Can anyone explain why?".  You're just giving a workaround - no explanation

Comment: Ohk. let me add that too

Comment: @Tibrogargan,  hope this explains well

Comment: @Tibrogargan, the question's title actually is `How do you move text from a div into an input value?` and this answer perfectly covers that. If we're going to be literal in extreme, the answer to `Can anyone explain why?` should be `Yes`

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález granted, but pedantic.  Since the OP was explicitly asking for for an explanation, not just a workaround, do you believe giving just a workaround is sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

The `contents()` you were trying to use is defined by the jQuery documentation as

> To get the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   including text and comment nodes

So, `contents()` is returning en entire object with all those children, comments and etc... that's why: `[Object Object]`. If you use `console.log($('#input').contents())` you will be able to see the entire object in the console.

So, in that case, it's better to use `text()`, that get only the text content of the element matched.

After getting the text, then set it to the input with `val()`;

the example below shows this. (I added a timer just to better represent the code working, you can remove it and let only the code that is inside).

Also, if you want to keep the text in the `div`, remove the part where I used `.text('')`;

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  input = $('#input').text();
  $('#output').val(input);
  $('#input').text('');
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='' id="output">
<div id="input">Abcdef 1234567890</div>
```